# Do creating a React app enables ES Modules?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, es6-modules

I am learning MERN and starting of the backend section I learned that we have to enable ESM in package.JSON to use import and export but in building frontend with react nothing has to be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React itself doesn't care.

Whether you do or don't need to configure anything depends on the tools you use for your frontend development.

Eg. create-react-app and Vite configure the bundlers they use to work with ESM, but if you start from scratch, with e.g. your own Webpack configuration, you'll need to figure out the configuration yourself.

Comment: so I can use commonJS syntax too?

Comment: Depends on the bundler configuration. I'd recommend ESM.